# Unity3d - Touch Input issue

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, multi-touch

I develop a game that need user to have a single touch to draw over to link multiple objects. Currently using mouse button as touch input with this code:

```
if(Input.GetButton("Fire1"))
    {
        mouseIsDown = true;
        ...//other codes
    }
```

It works fine with mouse but it will give me problem when I compile it for multi touch device. In multitouch device, if you have 2 fingers down, the middle point will be taken as the input. But if I already touch an object then with second finger down to screen, it will mess up my game input and give me havoc design.

What I want is to limit it to 1 touch only. If the second finger come touching, ignore it. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is all you need:

```
     if ((Input.touchCount == 1) && (Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Began))   {
            mouseIsDown = true;
            ...//other codes
     }
```

It will only fire when one finger is on the screen because of `Input.touchCount == 1`

Answer (score 0):

You are using Input.GetButton. A button is not a touch. You probably want to look at [Input.GetTouch](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html)

If you need to support multiple input-type devices, you may want to consider scripting your own manager to abstract this out somewhat.

Answer (score -1):

I would roll with a bit of polling!

so in your Update() I typically do something like this:

```
foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
{
    // Get the touch id of the current touch if you're doing multi-touch.
    int pointerID = touch.fingerId;        

    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        // Do something off of a touch.
    }
}
```

If you're looking for more info check this out:
[TouchPhases in Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TouchPhase.html)

Comment: He wants to detect one finger only and ignore others. The code you have will detect as many fingers as possible on the screen.

Comment: That is true, however I thought I'd throw this into the mix as a best practice, as he can manage finger id for instance if needed to ensure it's the same fingerid. I found this is a solid way to lock down any bugginess.

Comment: He can but your code does not have that.  Your if statement will always run if the two or more fingers are placed on the screen. Maybe you should implement the finger id in your code to help others.